# My RAMs shrunk with no apparent damage. 8gb to 4gb on both rams.

Tags: windows, memory, desktop-computer, sdram

My computer recently started rebooting randomly, or whenever there's a bit of shock on the table. I thought probably one of the slots are loose. And I found on my OS that my 8 x 2 = 16GB RAM was showing 8GB. I thought one of the memories has fried or something, so I pulled out to find out which one. It turns out it was both of them. Both of them got weirdly damaged.

When I pulled one out, the OS showed 4GB of memory. When it's placed back in, it shows 8GB.

What's this? Can a memory get damaged like this? - losing half it's size.

Answer (score 0):

No, RAM cannot just shrink like that. [Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/331645-30-installed-bios-windows-showing)

As for shutting down when it's being bumped, could be the battery connection, could be the HDD trying to protect itself when it senses hard vibrations. I would stop shaking the table while you use your laptop in any case, then it won't shut off.

Comment: It's a desktop PC, I checked the power outlet, PSU, and the cables. all fine. 


I know it can't shrink like that. But it did, and that's why I'm here.